# How to conduct conditional Cox regression for matched case-control study?

Tags: regression, survival, frailty

I am attempting to find a program that will let me conduct Cox regression on my matched case-control dataset.

Please assist.

p.s. I have STATA, SPSS, and MedCalc

Comment: It might help to explain more about your study design: how are cases and controls sampled?

Answer (score 4):

Half the battle with many questions is understanding the terminology. Matching implies within group (or within pair) correlation. Under appropriate circumstances matching can be dealt with paired t-tests, conditional logistic regression or mixed effects models.

In survival analysis (or time to event analysis), within group correlation is known as shared  [**FRAILTY**](http://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/working/wp-2003-032.pdf). [Stata](http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/usug2001/uk7.pdf) covers frailty pretty thoroughly.

An example of the use of Stata for Cox PH with frailty on the UCLA website from Hosmer & Lemeshow's book is [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/examples/asa2/chap9.htm).

[Here](http://user.demogr.mpg.de/jwv/pdf/Vaupel-MPS-5-1995-2.pdf) is a paper discussing the concept of shared frailty in twins.

An example is provided with Stata 11. See the 2nd last example [here](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?stcox). I'll copy from the STATA SURVIVAL ANALYSIS AND EPIDEMIOLOGICAL TABLES REFERENCE MANUAL [ST] (pp141-142).

```
webuse catheter, clear
list in 1/10

     +----------------------------------------------------------------+
     | patient   time   infect    age   female   _st   _d    _t   _t0 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |       1     16        1     28        0     1    1    16     0 |
  2. |       1      8        1     28        0     1    1     8     0 |
  3. |       2     13        0     48        1     1    0    13     0 |
  4. |       2     23        1     48        1     1    1    23     0 |
  5. |       3     22        1     32        0     1    1    22     0 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |       3     28        1     32        0     1    1    28     0 |
  7. |       4    318        1   31.5        1     1    1   318     0 |
  8. |       4    447        1   31.5        1     1    1   447     0 |
  9. |       5     30        1     10        0     1    1    30     0 |
 10. |       5     12        1     10        0     1    1    12     0 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

"Consider the data from a study of 38 kidney dialysis patients, as described in McGilchrist and
Aisbett (1991). The study is concerned with the prevalence of infection at the catheter insertion point.
Two recurrence times (in days) are measured for each patient, and each recorded time is the time
from initial insertion (onset of risk) to infection or censoring.

Each patient (patient) has two recurrence times (time) recorded, with each catheter insertion
resulting in either infection (infect==1) or right-censoring (infect==0). Among the covariates
measured are age and sex (female==1 if female, female==0 if male).

```
stset time, fail(infect)
stcox age female, shared(patient)
Cox regression --
         Breslow method for ties                Number of obs      =        76
         Gamma shared frailty                   Number of groups   =        38
Group variable: patient

No. of subjects =           76                  Obs per group: min =         2
No. of failures =           58                                 avg =         2
Time at risk    =         7424                                 max =         2

                                                Wald chi2(2)       =     11.66
Log likelihood  =   -181.97453                  Prob > chi2        =    0.0029

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          _t | Haz. Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         age |   1.006202   .0120965     0.51   0.607     .9827701    1.030192
      female |   .2068678    .095708    -3.41   0.001     .0835376    .5122756
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       theta |   .4754497   .2673108
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Likelihood-ratio test of theta=0: chibar2(01) =     6.27 Prob>=chibar2 = 0.006

Note: standard errors of hazard ratios are conditional on theta.
```

From the output, we obtain $\hat{\theta}$ = 0.475, and given the standard error of $\hat{\theta}$ and likelihood-ratio test of H0:$\theta$ = 0, we find a significant frailty effect, meaning that the correlation within patient cannot be ignored."

Me again.
This is similar to a twin study - two measurements in the same unit (i.e. two from one patient or one from each twin)
If we ignore frailty the estimates change, especially the sex effect:

```
stcox age female

Cox regression -- Breslow method for ties

No. of subjects =           76                     Number of obs   =        76
No. of failures =           58
Time at risk    =         7424
                                                   LR chi2(2)      =      6.67
Log likelihood  =   -185.10993                     Prob > chi2     =    0.0355

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          _t | Haz. Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         age |   1.002245   .0091153     0.25   0.805     .9845377    1.020271
      female |   .4499194   .1340786    -2.68   0.007     .2508832    .8068592
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Dummy variable model in response to Andy W's question (below):

```
gen pnum = patient -  floor(_n/2)
list in 1/10

     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | patient   time   infect    age   female   pnum   _st   _d    _t   _t0 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |       1     16        1     28        0      1     1    1    16     0 |
  2. |       1      8        1     28        0      0     1    1     8     0 |
  3. |       2     13        0     48        1      1     1    0    13     0 |
  4. |       2     23        1     48        1      0     1    1    23     0 |
  5. |       3     22        1     32        0      1     1    1    22     0 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |       3     28        1     32        0      0     1    1    28     0 |
  7. |       4    318        1   31.5        1      1     1    1   318     0 |
  8. |       4    447        1   31.5        1      0     1    1   447     0 |
  9. |       5     30        1     10        0      1     1    1    30     0 |
 10. |       5     12        1     10        0      0     1    1    12     0 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

stcox age female pnum

Cox regression -- Breslow method for ties

No. of subjects =           76                     Number of obs   =        76
No. of failures =           58
Time at risk    =         7424
                                                   LR chi2(3)      =      7.63
Log likelihood  =   -184.63204                     Prob > chi2     =    0.0543

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          _t | Haz. Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         age |   1.001207   .0091269     0.13   0.895     .9834779    1.019257
      female |   .4259506   .1295227    -2.81   0.005     .2347073    .7730221
        pnum |   .7639054   .2111721    -0.97   0.330     .4443606    1.313238
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The coefficients are different and the evidence of a sex effect has disappeared.

Comment: @Thylacoleo Thanks for the links (esp. the genetic related one). So, what Stata command would you recommend?

Comment: The question concerns Cox regression. I'll post an expmple (above) provided with Stata 11.

Comment: @Thylacoleo Ok, this was just to be sure that the `stcox` command was the correct approach.

Comment: @Thylacoleo, do you know if you included fixed effects for all the matched groups (ie dummy variables) would you get the same covariate coefficients when you define shared frailty?

Comment: @Andy W. No as frailty is a the equivalent of a random effect in survival analysis. So the cathetar model is equivalent to a mixed model with both fixed and random coefficients. To show this I'll add the dummy variable example above. Perhaps it could be interpreted as an "order effect" - second infection versus first.

Comment: @Thylacoleo (+1) Thanks for all of this. It looks definitively better with your annotated Stata example.

Comment: Why do you say that "The coefficients are different and the evidence of a sex effect has disappeared." Still HR=0.424 for gender (females) with p=0.005. There could be existing a frailty effect but it did not affect the gender effect.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Stata, you can just look at the `stcox` command. Examples are available from [Stata](http://www.stata.com/capabilities/survivalsession.html) or [UCLA](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/topics/survival.htm) website.
Also, take a look at [Analysis of matched cohort data](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0070) from the *Stata Journal* (2004 4(3)).

Under R, you can use the `coxph()` function from the `survival` library.

Comment: Also as a note to the poster you can not estimate the shared frailty in SPSS as in Thylacoleo's example. You can only include covariates in the Cox regression (either time varying or static).

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the tips. In fact, I don't really use SPSS (only from time to time for Factor Analysis, and to exchange with colleagues), but it might be of interest for SPSS users. (my +1)